# Ubuntu: fixing python installation

Tags: python, ubuntu

I've installed python 2.7.10 with Anaconda/ipython notebook, which now works fine. My new problems are:

1. Ubuntu Software Center won't launch
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade` generating the errors below.

Online advice is essentially to reinstall python. However, when I try

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python
```

I get

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

Since `$PYTHONHOME` is blank by default, I decided to leave it alone and take a look at my python installation inventory. **Question: shouldn't it be possible to create aliases or symbolic links to get the system python to work again rather than reinstalling anything?** Again, the objective here is just to get `apt` running correctly. Thanks.

```
/usr/bin/python,python2,python2.7,python3,python3.4
/usr/lib/python2.7,python3,python3.4 (folders)

/usr/local/bin/python,python2,python2.7
/usr/local/lib/python2.7,python3.4 (folders)
```

`-->` means symbolic link.

```
/usr/bin/python  --> /usr/local/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python2 --> /usr/bin/python2.7

/usr/local/bin/python  --> /usr/local/bin/python2
/usr/local/bin/python2 --> /usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

Error messages referred to above:

```
Setting up apport (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.18) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

and for specific applications:

```
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
dpkg: error processing package grass-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit     status 101
Setting up python-urllib3 (1.7.1-1ubuntu4) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 289, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 262, in main
options.force, options.optimize, e_patterns)
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 178, in compile
pipe.send(fn)
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 141, in py_compile
stdin.write(filename + '\n')
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
dpkg: error processing package python-urllib3 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit     status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
```

Comment: Did you at some point attempt to completely uninstall Python (particularly Python 2) from your system? This is why we use virtualenv for things in preference to installing packages locally. Linux uses a lot of Python and dependency management at the 'global' level so mixing your user stuff in with it is a terrible idea.

Comment: Although I didn't completely uninstall Python, I know I've renamed/linked folders to get Anaconda (and 2.10) to work properly, clobbering the system-wide python2 in the process. I've since learned about `venv` and working within its directory.

Comment: Check [this question over at Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187227/i-run-sudo-apt-get-remove-python2-7-can-i-restore-my-ubuntu-now): that user recursively removed Python 2 (which _uninstalled_ apt), leaving them in a worse position than you are. There are instructions there for trying to recover without just reinstalling the OS. BTW, if you end up reinstalling, as long as you can keep your $HOME dir, parts of /etc/, and a list of installed programs (to reinstall) it's pretty painless.

Comment: You might get some mileage out of installing a working Ubuntu onto a VM or laptop and using `rsync` or similar to make exact copies of its global Python directories, permissions and everything. If you can repair the damage that's undermining `apt`, you might be able to make a full recovery using it to reinstall broken packages. Make sure you create the same users in the same order as your main machine if you try this, to maximize the chances it works.

Comment: A reinstall is probably in my future. I'll give a manual python & dpkg install a try before taking the leap.

Comment: Good luck! Don't be too afraid if you have to do a reinstall. Hell, it's probably easier than manually rebuilding core packages; it's just time-consuming because you'll have to reinstall everything on your system that doesn't ship with it.